# WSSTUBE0025: Error in Verifying Security in the Inbound Message (Security Requirements not met - No Security header in message)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, soap, payara, wsit

I'm working on a web application, and I have to implement an interface to be able to encrypt the downloadable documents. The development environment is:

- Java 11
- Jakarta 10
- Payara 6 (Glassfish)

The interface is a SOAP service, so first of all I have generated the Java classes from the WSDL file (which I've got from the service team) with the `jaxws-maven-plugin`.

Regarding the certificates the service needs a JKS file which contains the followings:

- client private key + public certificate
- server public certificate

So I have created this JKS, imported the necessary certificates into it, and make it available for the application.

To attach this JKS to the Callback, I'm using a WSIT file (`wsit-client.xml`) to override the default policy of the WSDL:

```
    <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="...">
        <wsp:ExactlyOne>
            <wsp:All>
                <sc:TrustStore wspp:visibility="private" callbackHandler="..." peeralias="..."/>
                <sc:KeyStore wspp:visibility="private" callbackHandler="..." alias="..."/>
            </wsp:All>
        </wsp:ExactlyOne>
    </wsp:Policy>
```

The `callbackHandler` attribute points to our custom CallbackHandler, where we override the `handle` method to load our custom JKS. The `alias` and `peeralias` are the same aliases with which I have imported the certs into the JKS.

If I call the service, then I get this error:

```
"WSSTUBE0025: Error in Verifying Security in the Inbound Message.","StackTrace":"com.sun.xml.wss.XWSSecurityException: Security Requirements not met - No Security header in message
```

The complete stacktrace is the following:

```
"Exception":"WSSTUBE0025: Error in Verifying Security in the Inbound Message.","StackTrace":"com.sun.xml.wss.XWSSecurityException: Security Requirements not met - No Security header in message
    at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.incoming.SecurityRecipient.createMessage(SecurityRecipient.java:913)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.incoming.SecurityRecipient.validateMessage(SecurityRecipient.java:241)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityTubeBase.verifyInboundMessage(SecurityTubeBase.java:424)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityClientTube.processClientResponsePacket(SecurityClientTube.java:400)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityClientTube.processResponse(SecurityClientTube.java:331)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1117)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1020)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:989)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:847)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:431)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:160)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:78)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:62)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:132)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy517.protectDocument(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:588)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:408)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4835)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:653)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:834)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:603)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor336.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:888)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:833)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:603)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor251.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:888)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:833)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:603)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:72)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor243.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:888)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:833)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:375)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4807)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4795)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:90)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy369.protectDocument(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.Reflections.invokeAndUnwrap(Reflections.java:410)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:134)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:68)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:106)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.StreamingOutputProvider.writeTo(StreamingOutputProvider.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.StreamingOutputProvider.writeTo(StreamingOutputProvider.java:37)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.invokeWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:242)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:227)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:139)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.java:85)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:139)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:139)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.writeTo(MessageBodyFactory.java:1116)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.writeResponse(ServerRuntime.java:677)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.processResponse(ServerRuntime.java:385)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:375)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:264)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:265)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:697)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:394)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:346)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:357)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:311)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:205)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1554)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:757)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doChainInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:581)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:372)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:239)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:520)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:217)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:174)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:153)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:196)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:118)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:96)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:51)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:510)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:82)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:83)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:101)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:535)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:515)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

According to the logs the certificates are loading properly from the `CallbackHandler` (at least they are not null).

If I check the SOAP request, it has the security header:

```
<S:Header>
    <wsse:Security S:mustUnderstand=\"1\">
        ...
    </wsse:Security>
</S:Header>
```

Which I have tried so far:

- import the private key / public cert pair into the Payara keystore.p12 with the same alias as in the WSIT file
- import the server public cert into the Payara cacerts.p12 with the same alias as in the WSIT file
- set the `XWS_ClientProvider` and `XWS_ServerProvider` as the default providers for the SOAP layer
- create new providers (`com.sun.xml.wss.provider.wsit.WSITClientAuthModule` and `com.sun.xml.wss.provider.wsit.WSITServerAuthModule`) and set them as default

I'm starting to think that because of the "Inbound Message" the problem is not on our side. Do you have guys any idea?

Thanks